Existence of a positive measurable set with disjoint preimage under iterated transformation
Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ be a atomless probability measure space and $T:X\to X$ be a non-singular transformation such that $\mu\left({x\in X: T^n(x)=x}\right)=0$ for every $n\ge 1$. Let $A\in \mathcal B$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and $k\ge 1$ a positive integer. I want to show that there exists a set $E\in \mathcal B$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ with $E\subseteq A$ and $T^{-k}(E)\cap E=\emptyset$.
Let $E=A\setminus T^{-k}(A)$ and suppose $y\in T^{-k}(E)\cap E$. Then $y\in E$ implies $y\notin T^{-k}(A)$. Also, $y\in T^{-k}(E)$ implies $T^k(y)\in E$, which further implies $T^k(y)\in A$, hence $y\in T^{-k}(A)$. This contradiction shows that $T^{-k}(E)\cap E =\emptyset$. However, I am unable to construct the set $E$ from the given hypothesis such that $\mu(E)>0$. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your time and help.

What does "non-singular" mean in this context?

You will also need more specific assumptions. For example, if $A$ has no non-empty measurable subsets but is not a single point, then this can obviously fail.

@ChristianRemling "non-singular" means $\mu\left(T^{-1}(F)\right)=0 \implies \mu(F)=0$ for $F\in \mathcal B$. Now we can consider the space be atomless (since $T$ is aperiodic), then $A$ has a positive measurable subset.

@ChristianRemling, I've revised my question to include the condition of 'atomless space.'

Is it too much to assume that $(X,\mathcal{B})$ is countably separated, in the sense that there is a countable sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of measurable sets such that for any two points $x\neq y$ in $X$ there is $n$ such that $x\in A_n$ but $y\not\in A_n$ or viceversa? That condition is enough for existence of your set $E$

@SaúlRM, I'm not assuming it's countably separated, but could you please provide the proof assuming it is countably separated? It would be very helpful for me.

Okey. Although I just realized I was assuming that the map $T$ is measure preserving. Are you assuming this? Or something weaker like that $T$ preserves the measure class of $\mu$ (i.e. $T^{-1}$ preserves null sets)? Also, does $T$ being non-singular mean that it has a measurable inverse?

@SaúlRM we can assume $T$ is measure preserving.

The statement is false in general, I added a counterexample at the end of my answer to show that some separability condition like countable separability (or the stronger condition of being Lebesgue from KhashF's answer) is necessary. The counterexample is just a glorified identity map.
Here is a proof of the statement in the case that $(X,\mathcal{B})$ is countably separated, i.e, there exists a sequence $(A_n)_n$ of measurable sets such that if $x,y\in X$ are distinct then there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in A_n$ but $y\not\in A_n$ or viceversa.
Now as in the question, let $A\in\mathcal{B}$ satisfy $\mu(A)>0$, we want to find $E\subseteq A$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and $T^{-k}E\cap E=\varnothing$. It will be enough to find $E$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(T^{-k}E\cap E)=0$, and then we can remove a null set from $E$.
So suppose for the sake of contradiction that for all $E\in\mathcal{B}$ with $E\subseteq A$ and $\mu(E)>0$, we have $\mu(E\cap T^{-k}E)>0$.
Claim: Any measurable subset $E\subseteq A$ must satisfy $\mu(E\Delta T^{-k}E)=0$.
Proof: If $\mu(E\Delta T^{-k}E)>0$, then as $T$ is measure preserving we have $\mu(E\setminus T^{-k}E)>0$, and we also have $\mu((E\setminus T^{-k}E)\cap T^{-k}(E\setminus T^{-k}E))=\varnothing$, a contradiction.$\square$
In particular, $\mu(A\cap T^{-k}A)=0$ and letting $B_n:=A_n\cap A$, we have $\mu(B_n\Delta T^{-k}B_n)=0$. After removing a zero measure set from $X$ (remove $\bigcup_{i,j=0,1,\dots}T^{-ki}A\Delta T^{-kj}A$ from $X$ and similarly with each of the $B_n$, see ($*$) below for more details), we may assume that $T^{-k}A=A$ and $T^{-k}B_n=B_n$ for all $n$.
But then for any point $x\in A$, $T^kx\in A_n$ iff $x\in A_n$ for all $n$. Thus, $T^kx=x$. That is, the entire set $A$ is fixed pointwise by $T^k$, a contradiction.
($*$) Note that if $T:X\to X$ is a measure preserving transformation, $A$ is measurable and $\mu(A\Delta T^{-1}A)=0$, that implies that $\mu(T^{-n}(A\Delta T^{-1}A))=0$ for all $n$, that is, $\mu(T^{-n}A\Delta T^{n-1}A)=0$. Thus, all the sets $A,T^{-1}A,T^{-2}A,\dots$ have pairwise measure $0$ differences, that is, $\mu(T^{-n}A\cap T^{-m}A)=0$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. In fact, consider the set $Y=X\setminus\bigcup_{n,m=0,1,\dots}T^{-n}A\Delta T^{-m}A$. Then $T$ maps $Y$ to $Y$: indeed, if $Tx\not\in Y$ for some $x\in X$, then $Tx\in T^{-n}A\Delta T^{-m}A$ for some $m,n$. Thus, $x\in T^{-n-1}A\Delta T^{-m-1}A$, so $x$ is not in $Y$ either. So we may define $S:Y\to Y$ as the restriction of $T$, and then $S$ is measure preserving. Moreover, $S^{-1}(Y\cap A)$ is exactly $Y\cap A$: indeed, as $Y$ contains no points of $A\Delta T^{-1}A$, any $x\in Y$ satisfies $x\in A$ iff $Tx\in A$ iff $Sx\in A$.
Counterexample: Consider the space $X:=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{S}^1$, with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}:=\{\mathbb{Z}\times A;A\text{ Lebesgue measurable in }\mathbb{S}^1\}$, with probability measure $\mu(\mathbb{Z}\times A)=m(A)$ ($m$ being Lebesgue measure) and consider the map $f:X\to X;f((n,p))=(n+1,p)$.

thank you.But could you please explain the last line of the second-to-last paragraph? that is, how $\mu(\bigcup_{i,j} T^{-kj}A\Delta T^{-ki}A)=0$ and also with $B_n$ and from there how can we assume $T^{-k}A=A$ and $T^{-k}B_n=B_n$?

Yes, I added a more detailed explanation

@SaúlRM What is the probability measure in your counter example?

Thanks for catching that, I added it explicitly

If the map from your counter example is to be measure preserving, all subsets ${i}\times S^1 ,(i\in\Bbb{Z})$ must have the same measure . But their measures must add up to $\mu(\Bbb{Z}\times S^1)=1$.

@KhashF those sets are not measurable

If $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is a Lebesgue probability space, only the aperiodicity is needed by a simple application of Rokhlin's lemma: There exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $B,\dots,T^{-k}(B)$ are pairwise disjoint and $\mu\left(X\setminus\bigsqcup_{j=0}^{k}T^{-j}B\right)<\mu(A)$. Thus the intersection of $A$ with one of $B,\dots,T^{-k}(B)$, say $T^{-i}(B)$, is of positive measure. Now the subset $E:=A\cap T^{-i}(B)$ of $A$ works: $\mu(E)>0$ and $E\cap T^{-k}(E)$ is empty since it is contained in
$T^{-i}(B)\cap T^{-(k+i)}(B)=T^{-i}(B\cap T^{-k}(B))$
which is vacuous since $B\cap T^{-k}(B)=\emptyset$.

Thank you. Could you please provide me with the proof of the lemma?

This is a standard result. Check Wikipedia or this article for example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2239323_Rokhlin's_Lemma_for_Non-Invertible_Maps.
